# net::ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED error on electron app running on mac

Tags: reactjs, node.js, macos, electron

Getting error net::ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED while running electron app on mac OS for calling API locally on the MAC.
Any guess how to fix this error in electron app?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to use a Streams API? In that case, you can't use HTTP/1.1, you have to use HTTP/2 or QUIC, as the error said. Change your API server to accept HTTP/2 or QUIC connections.